# In spark," INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 10:24 records to ...."

Tags: apache-spark

I am processing a 500M text file(.gz) in amazon sc3 using spark and spark sql on amazon EMR(6 node clusters). And my program keep printing out " INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 10:24 records to /mnt/var/em/raw/i-d1bfb6dd_20150301_SparkSubmit_05013_raw.bin" for several hours.

My questions are:

1. what is the meaning of the log?
2. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's logging metrics, which would happen continuously. What are you concerned about? it's not a problem.

Comment: I want to know what it's doing in that step. What is saved?

Comment: How do I turn this logger off? I successfully turned off all other logging, but not this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sean said, it's just metrics and it's nothing to be concerned about. It will log messages like that on a regular basis even if you're not actively doing anything.

To suppress those messages, you can update the following line in `/home/hadoop/spark/conf/log4j.properties`.

Change `log4j.logger.amazon.emr.metrics=INFO` to `log4j.logger.amazon.emr.metrics=WARN`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ryan's answer, another way to turn this annoying thing off (in code instead of config):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getLogger("amazon.emr.metrics").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```